# Novel about kid's suburban life + some kids with powers

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult

I can only recall bits and pieces so bear with me:

I remember the book being about some kids in a small town fighting some kind of war with magical powers, and it was juxtaposed with the main character living a teenage suburban life.
The main protagonist's best friend was gay.
The main protagonist's mom was a state representative and was running for Congress.
There is one part where the main characters are driving at night and I believe they run over a deer. The main character might end up in the hospital? But I'm not entirely sure about that.

I know this isn't much to go on, but any help would be appreciated! I also recall the book was published in the 2010's.

Comment: Welcome to SFF! Please take a moment to [read our guide on story identification](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/62709) to see if there's any details you might be able to add.

Comment: How did the juxtaposition work--flashbacks? Was one of the lives imagined? Etc.